# How to edit the GNOME3 configuration in Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, gnome-3

I found the GUI version of the GNOME3 configuration but I'm interested in accessing the settings in a raw file and editing them.  For example, hide menu bar, hide the bottom task bar, turn off screen save etc... in a file rather than the built in tool.

Anyone know where I can find the file to edit?

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to know that Gnome3 uses the dconf-System to save the program settings. The dconf-System is based on a binary database, so how to change the settings?

At first you have to install the dconf-tools package:

```
apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then you can run the editor:

```
dconf-editor
```

Or you can use the command gsettings to modify the settings:

```
gesettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences \ default-folder-viewer 'list-view'
```

This example changes the view of nautilus to list by default.

You can write your own shell-script based on the gsettings command, which is an approach to your problem.

Gnome also starts a lot of programs automatically and you can modify this as well by editing the following file:

```
~/.config/autostart/*.desktop
```

I hope this helps :-)